# Get underlying value of a generic Enum

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types, enums

I want to generate the list of underlying values and names for a given generic `Enum` type. I want the native underlying values (as `object`s).

```
    public static ReadOnlyCollection<EnumerationMember> ListFromEnum<TEnum>()
    {
        Type enumType = typeof(TEnum);
        if (!enumType.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("TEnum is not an enum");
        }

        Type underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType);
        TEnum[] enumValues = (TEnum[])Enum.GetValues(enumType);

        return enumValues
            .Select(ev => new EnumerationMember(
                (???)ev,
                EnumerationExtension.GetDescription(enumType, ev)))
            .ToList()
            .AsReadOnly();
    }

    public class EnumerationMember
    {
        public EnumerationMember(object value, string description)
        {
            this.Value = value;
            this.Description = description;
        }

        public object Value { get; private set; }

        public string Description { get; private set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the simplest:

```
.Select(ev => Convert.ChangeType(ev, underlyingType))
```

But my preference would be to return a right-typed array - you don't even need the convert step then:

```
public static Array ListValuesFromEnum<T>()
{
    Type enumType = typeof(T);
    Type underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType);
    Array enumValues = Enum.GetValues(enumType);

    var arr = Array.CreateInstance(underlyingType, enumValues.Length);
    enumValues.CopyTo(arr, 0);
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: I considered that but I didn't know whether it would run it through a regular conversion function or just internally cast it to underlyingType. Is there some way to explicitly perform a cast using a Type or is this the same?

Comment: @Kurian well, I checked, and it seems to work - the boxed value is typed as `short` (etc), not `SomeEnum`. BTW, personally I'd try to return a `short[]` (via `Array` as the method's return type), but that's just me; the code for that isn't much different.

Comment: @Kurian ooh, found that if you use the right-typed array approach, the inbuilt value-preserving conversion handles it automatically - see the edit

Comment: I updated my question since your answer while correct, wasn't directly applicable to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some working code for you, it uses [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx)

```
public static ReadOnlyCollection<EnumerationMember> ListValuesFromEnum<T>()
{
    Type enumType = typeof(T);
    Type underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType);
    T[] enumValues = (T[])Enum.GetValues(enumType);

    return enumValues
        .Select(ev => new EnumerationMember(Convert.ChangeType(ev,underlyingType), ev.ToString()))
        .ToList()
        .AsReadOnly();
}
```

And here's a live demo: http://rextester.com/EHOE12097

Comment: This works even for my updated question, but I'm interested in a more efficient method than Convert.ChangeType.

Comment: more *efficient* method? Is there anything particulary *inefficient* about this method?

Comment: I'm not sure if it simply performs a cast internally or runs it through some conversion function.

Comment: So you don't know if this is efficient or not, you're just guessing. If you don't have a benchmark for efficiency how am I supposed to answer your question?

Comment: I based it on the implied improved efficiency in the previous answer.

Comment: According to MSDN it uses the IConvertible interface which I presume is less efficient than a direct cast to the underlying type.